# Select a specific date for the current year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that needs to select `{current year}-05-31 00:00:000`. Is there a way I can do it **without** just concatenating the year on to that string?

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 30, DATEADD(mm, 4, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)))
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik SSMS 2012 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Here is what I have now, I just didn't know if there was a simpler way: `SELECT DATEADD(dd, 30, DATEADD(mm, 4, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)))`

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to concat the year on to the string? FWIW, you can get the current year by using `YEAR(GETDATE())` - but I know that is not your question.

Comment: @ragerory SSIS needs the column to be a datetime. I know I could cast it, but I was just trying to see if there was something a little... cleaner.

Comment: @joelforsyth gotcha -- makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HVD's method is probably the simplest:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2000,'20000531')
```

In SQL 2012 and above, they made it really easy.

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),05,31)
```

Comment: DATEFROMPARTS is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, but unfortunately the server is 2008. Thanks @hvd

Comment: I figured you were looking for DATEFROMPARTS even though you can't use it now, it's good for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have performance issues you can use:

```
DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,CAST('2018-05-31 00:00:000' AS DATETIME), GETDATE()),CAST('2018-05-31 00:00:000' AS DATETIME))
```

This is a solution for not concat the year.

Comment: This approach seems viable, but I think your version is unnecessarily complicated. How about `DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE())-2000, '20000531')`? (Your number 2018 works just as well, of course.)

Comment: You are right. Your solutions just more simple. If you want to be more flexible (use this an date columns or have a date variable) it's more easy to have this complicated stement.